# Database create in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

I am using **Ubuntu 12.10** and recently I install **XAMPP 1.8.1**. My problem I can not create new database  using both **sql** command and **phpmyadmin**. In **phpmyadmin** database creation input box is not shown and **sql** command is not works. Here I use sql command as

```
 CREATE DATABASE my_db
```

But I can easily create table and run other `sql` command as like windows. How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the standard MySQL installation (I'm not sure what XAMPP installs) I've found it rather easy to use the [MySQL GUI Tools](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) to handle some of the administration tasks for MySQL. MySQL Server Administrator allows for the creation of databases, tables, users, setting privileges and much more. It can be run from another computer on your network and only requires that you have either root or admin user privileges for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

To create a database, your user needs the appropriate privileges. A lot of shared hosting providers only give you one database.

When your user does not have the correct permissions, PHPMyAdmin will detect this and hide the buttons/commands to do this.

When not on shared hosting, your username needs the global privilege 'create' to create a database.

A user with the 'grant' privilege needs to give you this privilege.

Comment: What does the server return when you try to create a database using the give sql?